# How do I call a basic YUI3 function from within a normal JavaScript function?

Tags: yui, yui3

I'd like to call a simple YUI3 function from within a JavaScript function.
Here is some code that does what I want in a very verbose way:

```
function changeContent (message) {
    YUI().use("node", function(Y) {
        Y.all('#content-div').setContent(message);
    });
}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

**NOTE:** I don't want to attach this function to any event, I just want a global changeContent() function available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the API to exist outside of the YUI().use(...function (Y) { /* sandbox */ }), you can capture the returned instance from YUI().

```
(function () { // to prevent extra global, we wrap in a function
    var Y = YUI().use('node');

    function changeContent(message) {
        Y.one('#content-div').setContent(message);
    }

    ...
})();
```

Be aware that there is a race condition here if you use the seed file (yui-min.js) and dynamic loader to pull in the other modules.  changeContent could be called before the Node API is loaded and added to Y.  You can avoid this by using a combo script up front.  You can get the combo script url from [the YUI 3 Configurator](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/configurator/).  There is a performance penalty for loading the modules in a blocking manner up front.  You may or may not notice this in your application.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
(function(){
    YUI().use("node", function(Y) {
         APP = {
    changeContent: function(message){
        Y.all('.content-div').setContent(message);      
    }
         };
    });
})();
```

Then, you can call changeContent by calling `APP.changeContent(message);` from anywhere you want. Hope this helps. :D