# Calling function from outside YUI sandbox

Tags: yui, javascript, javascript-framework

Picking up on YUI and see some opportunities in using the [YQuery tool](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/yquery) to load jQuery in a specific implementation where the YUI 3 sandbox approach would be useful.

However, I am struggling to figure out how I can access jQuery functions/variables defined within the YQuery sandbox.

Please see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    YUI().use('gallery-yquery', function(Y) {
        var jq = Y.YQuery();
        jq.version = '1.7.1';
        jq.use( function() {
            $.someFunc = function() {
                // Some Jquery actions
            }
        });
    });
</script>

...

<input type="button" onclick="$.someFunc();" value="someTest"/>
```

Is there a way I can get at "**$.someFunc**" such as from the button?

Note that this example just happens to be YQuery and that the question is on whether/how functions/variables defined within the YUI "sandbox" can be accessed from outside this on the same page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019805/how-do-i-call-a-basic-yui3-function-from-within-a-normal-javascript-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the return value of the use() method, without specifying a callback function as the last parameter.
I guess you might run into concurrency issues if using YUI dynamic loader since you won't be able to detect when the given instance has every needed dependencies loaded and ready.

```
var foo = YUI().use("yui", "event");
alert(foo.guid());
alert(foo.Event.generateId(document.body));
```

via: [yuilibrary](http://yuilibrary.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=8108&sid=1c1f6e6966e213e264b0917cc71bf15a#p8108)

Comment: I can now see why YUI has a rep of being too complicated. I need a rethink on using this. Thanks for the answers and links.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, just `jQuery.someFunc()` ?